# Blazor not show Not Found page for files endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, routes, blazor, blazor-server-side

For some kind of reasons, Blazor not show the "Not Found" page, created in `App.razor`, when users type on their browser a endpoint like a files (example: localhost:5001/unexist.file)

**Example when endpoint contains points**
[image]

**App.razor**

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
  <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" >
    ....
    <NotFound>
       <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
       ...
       My custom Not Found page content
       ...
       </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
  </Router>
  <NavigationTracker />
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

This work correctly only if endpoint doesn't contains any point characters.
There is a possibility to control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Microsoft doc I found this [helpful information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#routing-with-urls-that-contain-dots)

Basically the method depends on the hosting model:

In your case **Blazor server**(as your tag says). to do it we need change program.cs as follow:

```
app.MapFallbackToPage("/{param?}", "/_Host");
```

In  **blazor web assembly hosted in ASP.Net** we change it as follows:

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("/{param?}", "index.html");
```

explanation from Microsoft docs:

> the server-side default route template assumes that if the last
> segment of a request URL contains a dot (.) that a file is requested.
> For example, the URL https://localhost.com:5001/example/some.thing is
> interpreted by the router as a request for a file named some.thing.
> Without additional configuration, an app returns a 404

Last thing I discovered while searching, is that I was unable to change the route behavior when running web assembly standalone without dotnet host. If I were to publish it, it can be change depending on the host, like changing web.config, but I had no luck when in debugging mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a previous version of .Net, or you have an old scaffolding, you need change this configuration in `Program.cs` like this:

```
...
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   ...
   endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/{param?}", "/_Host");
});
```